# Jointjs error on Nodejs server - Uncaught ReferenceError:Joint is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jointjs

I have the following code to make sample diagram on a file on node server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>newpageshere</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="joint.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<script src="joint.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#myholder'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});

var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
});

var rect2 = rect.clone();
rect2.translate(300);

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect.id },
    target: { id: rect2.id }
});

graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run it, it shows nothing. In the developer console I get the following error on the line
    `var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;`

Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: joint is not defined

The file seem to work good when I run it on a XAMPP localhost but not when I run it on a node.js server. Is there something more that I have to configure the server on or can anyone see a mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

If `joint` is not defined, it seems like the joint.js file is not properly loaded. Or is it? You can check this in the Network tab of the Developer Tools of your browser. If that's indeed the case, then you have to check what's your root directory for serving static files (the scripts/stylesheet) on your server-side.